# Error: "unable to infer src variant" with Anchor Enums

Tags: anchor

I have an Enum defined in my Anchor Program that I pass to some instructions and that has this format:

```
pub enum MyEnum {
    VALUE,
}
```

In my tests, I use it like so:

```
program.methods.someInstruction({vALUE: {}}).accounts().signers([someSigner]).rpc();
```

This also aligns with what the typehints say, which describe my enum like this:

```
({} & {
    vALUE: Record<string, never>;
})
```

Unfortunately, this gives me the error `unable to infer src variant` when I try to run it. I've also tried `{vALUE: null}` and `{vALUE: undefined}` but the error persists. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more trial and error it turns out this is a bug with anchor around enums written in capslock. When I do `{value: {}}` (so all small letters) it works fine, even though typescript then throws me an error along the lines of `Type at position x in source is not compatible with type at position x in target.`. However, I simply use `// @ts-ignore` on this to shut it up and it works fine.

Edit: I was going to open an issue for this, but it seems this has [already been done](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/pull/2763) and a fix has been merged two months ago, so this hopefully won't be a problem in v0.30.0 anymore.